# If statement not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm Simply trying to change the text on a `UILabel` on a Friday between 4 and 6pm using the below code but the if statement is not being called? I am using a subclass of `UILabel` via Interface Builder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(targetMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)targetMethod {
    NSLog(@"Called Timer");

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE hh mm"];
    NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
    NSString *dayAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:dt];
    NSArray *array = [dayAsString componentsSeparatedByString: @""];
    if([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Friday"] && [[array     objectAtIndex:1] intValue]>=4 &&  [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue]<=6 &&   [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue]>=0 && [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue]  <=59)
    {
        self.scrollingLabel.text = @"On Air";
        NSLog(@"On Air");
    }
    else 
    {
        self.scrollingLabel.text = @"Off Air";
        NSLog(@"Off Air");
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: before checking it just print the value of [array objectAtIndex:0] because its not gave you "Friday" its print "fri" as Ramana gave you ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have made 2 mistakes**

1. `[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE hh mm"];` in this `"EEE"` will show only 3 characters of day like "Fri".
2. `NSArray *array = [dayAsString componentsSeparatedByString: @""];` will return only one object in array.

**Now you need to do**

1. Either change "Friday" to "Fri" in you if condition or use `"EEEE"` (4E) that will return full name like "Friday".
2. Separate by single space in `NSArray *array = [dayAsString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];`

Comment: Works perfectly when using "EEEE", also the most thorough answer. Thanks

Comment: @mv79, Happy to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to split time with spaces string it?

```
NSArray *array = [dayAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

And `"EEE"` will return `"Fri"`, not `"Friday"`.

---

Also, if you need to manipulate date/time you can look at this library : [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)

```
#import "DateTools.h"

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
if (date.weekday == 6 && date.hour >= 16 && date.hour <= 18) {
    NSLog(@"On Air");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Off Air");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will definitely have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

setDateFormat:@"EEE hh mm"

With 3 E's in the date format, it returns short version of Weekday, like "Fri".

I think you need to change the comparison from "Friday" to "Fri"

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your components are not being separated into individual elements at all. You forgot the space in the quotes after the 'componentsSeparatedByString' method. It should be:

```
NSArray *array = [dayAsString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```

I tested it out, and the if statement should be called and return the specified output. 
Also, the first element returns only the first three characters of the day, such as 'Tue' for Tuesday. Change Friday to 'Fri' and you should be good.

Comment: This was part of the problem, thanks for your response.